# Truncate float (not rounded) to 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript, floating-point, rounding

Please, I need convert **String** into **Float** or **Double** in Javascript. But I don't want it round it. I want just fixed 2 decimal places **Number** which means input *0.996* return me *0.99* and not 1.

```js
// 1. Convert number to float strip to 2 decimal places
var total = ',996' // (or 0.996 if you want, doesn't matter)
total = Math.round(parseFloat(
                   total.replace (',', '.')
)).toFixed(2);

console.log ( typeof total );
console.log ( total );
```

After this, `total` is not a number anymore. It's a String with value 1

It's possible to convert string into decimal number with 2 fixed places without rounding?

If you're interested about simple spent manager, I'm programmit it here
https://codepen.io/littleTheRabbit/pen/JjYWjRG

Thank you very much for any advice

**Best Regards**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done by dropping the extra digits you don't want by using multiplication and division.  For example, if you want 0.994 to be 0.99, you can multiply by 100 (to cover 2 decimal places), then truncate the number, and then divide it back by 100 to it to the original decimal place.

example:

```
  0.994 * 100 = 99.4
  99.4 truncated = 99.0
  99.0 / 100 = 0.99
```

So here is a function that will do that:

```js
const truncateByDecimalPlace = (value, numDecimalPlaces) =>
  Math.trunc(value * Math.pow(10, numDecimalPlaces)) / Math.pow(10, numDecimalPlaces)

console.log(truncateByDecimalPlace(0.996, 2)) // 0.99
```

Comment: Sorry, what does it mean "y" ? It's not declared

Comment: Ah, sorry, that was suppose to be 'value'; I've edited my answer

Comment: Works great! Thank you

Comment: The code in this answer produces incorrect results for some numbers. For example, when `value` is 1.339999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375, the result should be 1.33, but this produces 1.34 (as printed, 1.3400000000000000799360577730112709105014801025390625 as the number before formatting).

Comment: That's a different issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript